# Migrating Applications to new Environment

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

We are in the process of migrating .Net Windows desktop apps to a new environment. All that needs to be updated is the app.config database connection strings.

Is it possible to create 2 configurations for each application? So not to break existing working environment.

Basically I want to have connection strings for existing environment and for new environment.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: This describes your requirement for web.config files, but I believe it is possible for app.config files, too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @pm_2 I don't believe it works out of the box, without some additional plugin, e.g. SlowCheetah. I would love to be proven wrong here though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Configuration and Add ConfigurationSection on runtime

```
Configuration applicationConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.
              OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap()
    {ExeConfigFilename = path_to_your_config,ConfigurationUserLevel.None
                                );
```

Here

```
applicationConfiguration.Sections.Add("section",new YourSection())
applicationConfiguration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full,true);
```